# weird variable arguments issue in C

Tags: c, variables, clang

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in the last statement when calling the following simplified function:

```
void test(char *param, ...) {
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl, param);
  double a = va_arg(vl, double);
  double b = va_arg(vl, double);
  double *result = va_arg(vl, double*);
  *result = a*b;
  va_end(vl);
}
```

The function is called with:

```
double result;
test("blub", 3, 3, &result);
```

I'm using Xcode's clang compiler (Apple LLVM compiler 3.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in you sending a `double` as `3` instead of `3.0`. A normal `3` will be treated as integer but in the `test` function you are retrieving doubles which are bigger than an `int` on most platforms and you might end up reading wrong locations which inturn leads to  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` run time signal being generated